# Change height of a list item without affecting other list items

Tags: css

I have a footer that contains nothing but an unordered list which looks like this:

[image]

I'm trying to create a hover state which looks like this:

[image]

So when you hover over a list item, it expands upwards and reveals an image below.

Everything I've tried so far to achieve this causes all list items to expand in height when one list item does; I can't seem to get the hovered list item to expand in height without affecting all the others as well. I'm also having trouble figuring out how to get the "Text" part of the list item to stay at the top of the list item in the hover state.

EDIT:
Please note that the number of list items is dynamic, and the site is responsive. I need the list items to always fill out the full width of the browser window (regardless of how wide the window is, and how many list items there are). I'm using `display: table` and `table-layout: fixed` on the unordered list and `display: table-cell` on the list items to achieve this.

I also need for the `a` to fill the entire list item, so that clicking on the image or on the text area will take the user to the `a href="..."` location.

Here's a jsFiddle with my current HTML and CSS:
http://jsfiddle.net/tsfMD/

My current HTML is:

```
<footer>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

My current CSS is:

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
}

footer ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

footer ul li {
  margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  border-right: 1px solid #d1d2d4;
  border-left: 1px solid #d1d2d4;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  background-image: url('http://puu.sh/4ySYl.png');
  background-position: center bottom;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

footer ul li:hover {
  height: 230px;
}

footer ul li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}

footer ul li:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

footer ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 0 40px;
}
```

Comment: Without the use of Javascript, I presume?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tsfMD/3/)?

Comment: Ignore the one I have posted above, Soulwish's answer seems a lot lot more simple :)

Comment: Thanks Harry, yours seems to be working as intended. The only issue is I need to use a CSS transition between the two states, but you can't transition the `display` property. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jordan: You are correct. `display` breaks transitions. Let me see if I can find any other options.

Comment: Thanks, Harry. Please note that I also have another constraint: I also need for the `a` to fill the entire list item, so that clicking on the image or on the text area will take the user to the `a href="..."` location. Your current solution has the image outside of the `a` tag.

Comment: @Jordan: Check if [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tsfMD/4/) is OK. I am modifying the `height` on `hover` so that it can be transitioned. I shall look into the `a` bit now.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use a transition like that, as it warps the image while increasing its height. I need the "Text" part to get pushed upwards and reveal the image below it as it comes up.

Comment: @Jordan: I seem to have run out of options mate. Let us hope somebody comes with a good solution. In the meantime, I will see if I get any ideas.

Answer (score 3):

Jordan. In this case you should use inline-block (not table-cell) for your list items. This will allow you to have dynamic height for each separate list item. So, instead of

```
footer ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

you should use

```
footer ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

All other styles and properties can stay the same.

Also, I've updated your [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/tsfMD/1/).

Comment: Good answer but share your code instead of highlighting text, will upvote you if you do so and explain OP what you did there

Comment: This is much better mate :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, @Mr. Alien and Harry. I'm new here :)

Comment: @Soulwish upvoted now :) and we force users to share their code cuz if the fiddle link is dead, your answer will be useless :)

Comment: I should have specified this in the question, but I can't just change the list items to display as inline-blocks because the site is responsive and I need the list items to fill out the full width of the browser window at all times, and regardless of how many of them exist.

Comment: @Jordan: Ah I see, in that case check if the option I posted in comments suits you. That involves changes to the markup as well.